# Is there a way to select your broswer's scrollbar using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am creating a sidebar that expands and collapses when clicked from the right side of a page; I want to be able to select the scrollbar to find the z-index of it in order to change it so that when the sidebar expands outward, it is nested underneath the scrollbar.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the scrollbar is part of the browser's chrome. The only things you can access are what's inside the browser window and not part of the browser. Now, what you can try is setting body height manually and setting the body's overflow to hidden. Then you shouldn't get a scrollbar, but you need to allow the user to scroll some other way if necessary.